# Name of Song this jazz melody comes from

Tags: jazz, melody

Can someone please tell me the name of the song this melody can be heard? comes from some hard bop tune in the 70's or something I don't know

https://musescore.com/scores/unknown/unknown-831278829921673?share=copy_link

Comment: There are a couple of stray accidentals there, that are superfluous.

Comment: sorry about that do you know the name of the song?

Comment: The remit of this site discourages questions relating to finding titles, etc. Check the help Centre for details. Might have better results on Music Fans.